# C#: calculating time diff

Tags: c#

using the following:-

```
TimeSpan diff = dt2.TimeOfDay - dt1.TimeOfDay;
```

d1, d2 are 2 variables of type `DateTime` and they have got values in them

Now I want to check if there's a difference of 12 hours b/w them

```
if(diff>12)

{
//do stuff
}
```

now of course it wont wont coz 12 is an int..so how do I check if the time is more than 12 hrs or not ?? need help with this if statement only..thnx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general solution is to construct a `TimeSpan` object that corresponds to the cut-off:

```
if(diff > TimeSpan.FromHours(12))
{
   ...
}
```

If the cut-off corresponds to a multiple of a 'nice' unit of time like days, hours, minutes, seconds or milliseconds as in your example, you could use the `TotalXXX` property of `TimeSpan`, as others have posted:

```
if(diff.TotalHours > 12)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: both methods will check the same ?

Comment: Yes, they will check exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

To plainly answer your question, you use one of the properties on the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) struct, typically the [TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) property. There are other, simpler, answers here that tells you how to do that, so I won't repeat it.

However, this means I must trust your question to be complete, and I think that just ignoring the date portion will give you edge-cases that you at least need to know about.

For instance, with the following two time-of-day values, how much time is between them?

```
18:00
08:00
```

Is it `-10` hours, or `14`hours between these two?

To properly answer your question, personally I would want you to tell me how you intend to use these values, what it means to you, and give a few examples.

Comment: So do I need to use TotalHours() or FromHours() ??

Comment: His point is that using TimeOfDay will give you these corner cases. It does not matter if you use TotalHours or FromHours. Since TimeOfDay strip the date part away, 18:00 on Tuesday will be a "higher" value than 14:00 on Wednesday, and that is probably not the functionality you are after. Any reason why you use TimeOfDay, and not just dt2 - dt1 ?

Comment: My day-job is working with dates, times, and periods of such, and I'm just inherently suspicious when you start comparing time-of-day only and start to ask "how many hours between these". I need to know what you intend to use that value for, what meaning it has to you. As such, I want you to answer my question, is it -10 hours or +14 hours between the two time-of-day values I posted.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
if( diff.TotalHours > 12){
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually used intellisense and noticed the `Hours` and `TotalHours` properties on the diff TimeSpan object?

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan.FromHours you need to use to find the difference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan diff = dt2.Substract(dt1);
if (diff.TotalHours > 12)
{
  // Do something
}
```